# how to make blur all option after select 2 from 4?[jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want select 3 option from many.After select 3 option,all option will be blur so that anyone can't select more.

Here I added my code,please check it.

[Link to File](https://files.fm/f/v4ghgtze3)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>want to select</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>


<style>
.select {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.fill {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>

<body>



<div class="select" id="1">Egg</div>
<div class="select" id="2">mango</div>
<div class="select" id="3">apple</div>
<div class="select" id="4">egg</div>
<div class="select" id="5">apple</div>
<div class="select" id="6">egg</div>




</body>
<script>
$('.select').click(function(e){
    var $et = $(e.target);
    if ($et.hasClass('fill')) { 
        $et.removeClass('fill');
    } else {
        if ($('.fill').length < 3) {
            $et.addClass('fill');
             $et.blur();
        }
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I moved the content of your Link into your Post. Please be reminded that you want to supply a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.select').click(function(e) {
    var $et = $(this);
    if ($et.hasClass('fill')) {
      $et.toggleClass('fill');
    } else if ($et.parent().find(".fill").length < 3) {
      $et.toggleClass('fill');
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.select {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.fill {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="select" id="1">Egg</div>
  <div class="select" id="2">mango</div>
  <div class="select" id="3">apple</div>
  <div class="select" id="4">egg</div>
  <div class="select" id="5">apple</div>
  <div class="select" id="6">egg</div>
</div>
```

Adding a wrapper allows for better reference to the parent. You can then check how many `.fill` elements there are inside the wrapper. Now you can conditionally remove or add `fill` class.